# Как суммировать свойство нескольких объектов?

Tags: javascript

Нужно суммировать свойство объектов `price`

```js
var storage = [{
    cat: {
      name: "Garfield",
      count: 3443,
      price: 1000
    }
  },
  {
    bird: {
      name: "Eagle",
      count: 4042,
      price: 3000
    }
  },
  {
    dog: {
      name: "Rex",
      count: 1488,
      price: 2000
    }
  }
];

function getTotalCost(storage) {
  return storage.map(object => Object.values(object)[0].price);
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < Object.values(object)[0].price.length; i++) {
    sum += Object.values(object)[0].price[i];
  }
  return sum;

}
console.log(getTotalCost(storage));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первой же строке функции `getTotalCost` вы возвращаете результат выполнения `map`, но вы только получили массив сумм, далее можно использовать функцию [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) для получения суммы :

```js
var storage = [{
    cat: {
      name: "Garfield",
      count: 3443,
      price: 1000
    }
  },
  {
    bird: {
      name: "Eagle",
      count: 4042,
      price: 3000
    }
  },
  {
    dog: {
      name: "Rex",
      count: 1488,
      price: 2000
    }
  }
];

function getTotalCost(storage) {
  return storage.map(object => Object.values(object)[0].price).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
}
console.log(getTotalCost(storage));
```

Comment: А зачем нужен лишний шаг с `map`? Можно же сразу использовать `reduce`.